# Lombok works on Liberica JDK 17?

Tags: java, lombok

I've been working on a project using BellSoft Liberica JDK v17, IntelliJ 2022.1 and SpringBoot 2.6.7. I have noticed that he has not recognized my entries from Lombok. I have searched for information and it seems that in version 16 of this JDK with external libraries such as Lombok. But I can't find anything for 17.

Could you tell me if the incompatibility exists and if I should use another version? Thanks to everyone for your support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have used Lombok 1.18.22 for jdk17 and spring boot 2.6.2. it works fine for me. can you please share your Lombok version?

Answer (score 0):

Liberica JDK is only JDK like OpenJDK and so on.
Lombok support Java 17.
Accordingly, it will work with Liberica JDK.
I myself use Liberica JDK 17 full (with JavaFX) on home development with Spring Boot and Lombok ;)